# How to create a secure web app (safe to enter SSN)?

Tags: javascript, security, ssl

I would like to create a web app that:

- takes in personal data (including SSN) using a csv
- processes and manipulates the data in the browser javascript
- outputs a pdf

Since everything happens in the browser and none of the data is stored in a database at the web host does an SSL certificate provide sufficient security?

Comment: If everything is done client side, and the code is properly written, then yes an SSL certificate is generally considered to be secure enough.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate only helps that the script is securely send from your server to the clients browser and that no manipulation can be done in between. It does not help against

- Manipulation at the server side. It is actually very common that servers gets hacked and the stored applications gets modified for delivery of malware and similar.
- Client-Side Cross-Site-Scripting attacks, i.e. DOM XSS. Since what you do is fairly complex chances are high that you fail to protect against such an attack.
- Other Cross-Site-Scripting: if the script you serve to the user depends on the user, cookies or whatever (that is not a static script) you might be vulnerable to other XSS attacks too.

So in general the answer is that SSL is not sufficient alone.